# Inequalities of quadratic form

Tags: inequality, quadratic-forms

We know that the below inequality holds if A is positive definite

${\lambda _{\min }}\left( {{A}} \right){\left\| x \right\|^2} \le {x^T}{A}x$ or equivalently  $\alpha{\left\| x \right\|^2} \le {x^T}{A}x$ where $\alpha>0$

Is there any other condition that the above inequality can still hold?

Comment: Well for non-symmetric real $A$ if $\lambda_{\min}(A+A^T)>0 \Rightarrow x^TAx\geq \alpha\|x\|^2$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Comment: May I know the proof for that statement or is there any reference that i can find the proof?

Comment: It follows directly from the fact that $x^TAx=x^TA^Tx$ (note that this is a scalar quantity and cannot change under transposition). Then, $x^TAx=\frac{1}{2}x^T(A^T+A)x$. Since $A+A^T$ is symmetric the minimum eigenvalue argument holds true.